# run-time error 50012 - Method "Export" of object 'VBComponent' failed error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code to transfer a module and a user form from one workbook to another that works on multiple systems. However, I have 2 users that it fails with the error

"Run-Time error '50012' - Method 'Export' of object 'VBComponent' failed"

The code is as follows:

```html
Public Sub TransferModule2()
Const MODULE_NAME    As String = "Module5"         ' Name of the module to transfer
Const UserForm As String = "UserForm1"
Dim ID As String
ID = Environ("USERNAME")

Dim TEMPFILE As String
TEMPFILE = "C:/Users/" & ID & "/Desktop/Modul.bas" ' temp textfile
TEMPFILE2 = "UserForm.frm"
   
   ' On Error Resume Next
   '**Create new workbook
   
   '** export the module to a textfile
   Workbooks(Module4.GetBook3).VBProject.VBComponents(MODULE_NAME).Export fileName:=TEMPFILE
  
   'import the module to the new workbook
   Workbooks(TemplateBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Import fileName:=TEMPFILE
   
   Workbooks(Module4.GetBook3).VBProject.VBComponents(UserForm).Export fileName:=TEMPFILE2
    Workbooks(TemplateBook).VBProject.VBComponents.Import fileName:=TEMPFILE2
  
   'kill the textfile
   Kill TEMPFILE
   Kill TEMPFILE2
End Sub
```

The error occurs on the first export code. I have enabled Visual Basic Object Project Mode on these computers and it still fails, but has no issues on any other computer. The computers were imaged at the exact same time as mine, and the file is in a single location so there are no code modifications. We are running the exact same version of Office with the exact same updates.

What could be conflicting with this export object statement that isn't a reference library or a versioning issue?

Comment: could it be access privileges? can the users write to `C:/Users/`?

Comment: If you comment out the `Export` line do the other lines work?

Comment: WhiteHate - It actually defaults to their desktop, and they have write access. I've also built custom access to a specific folder on their computer and it still fails.

Comment: Tim - If I comment out the export line the import line fails. The user form code works though, which is completely confusing. I would have thought the userform move would fail too, but it doesn't.

Comment: "I have enabled Visual Basic Object Project Mode" - this terminology is odd do you mean you checked the "Trust Access to the VBA Project Object model" checkbox in the Excel Options?

Comment: What is the exact value returned by (eg) `Module4.GetBook3` and does that differ on the "problem" PC's ?  Something to do with Explorer folder options >> "hide extensions for known file types".  I recall something along those lines.

Comment: Tim - #1 You are correct. Sorry for the confusion. I was giving a training for the package this code is a part of and hurriedly typed a response. #2 It's a variable that has the source workbook name. I've validated that is has a valid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the two users in question have different ID's for their login than the location where their desktop lives. I'm unsure why IT did this, but it turns out this was a location issue within the TEMPFILE path. I don't know why I didn't catch that it let me use the default path on the UserForm transfer, as if I had of looked deeper I would have seen that was the solution.