# Excel VBA Export Modules Application-defined or object-defined error: 50012

Tags: excel, vba, export, runtime-error

after a recommendation from this Website i use this code to export VBA code: [Export VBA Modules](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm), i use it to export 20+ modules/userforms and about 70% of the time i execute the export makro at least one of the exports ([this export code line throws error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIdiK.png)) throws an Application-defined or object-defined error (err nr: 50012).

All i found was this: [stackoverflow export error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753140/run-time-error-50012-method-export-of-object-vbcomponent-failed-error), however this cant be my problem since i just copied the code into my own VBA Project. This problem seems odd to me, since there are sometimes errors exporting modules, sometimes not. Also it seems random which modules export succesfully and which ones fail to export.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of errors, maybe with Application.Wait or DoEvents?

Comment: *here are sometimes errors, sometimes not* This is too broad. I'm afraid you'll need to be more specific. Debug your code step by step with F8, and try to detect what modules fail to be exported, and what lines cause the error.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks, i updated my question, the cmpComponent.Export line is the one that causes the error (the line that exports the module..). The modules that fail to export are random, its always between 1 and 5 of like 20+ modules, but they are usually different ones..

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns if i run the code "manually" with F8, there are no errors at all, maybe i actually can reduce the error count if the code runs "slower" ?

Comment: Sometimes that happens. The code goes *too fast* and you need to *slow it*. Probably you'll need command `DoEvents` (you can google for it) after that line that fails sometimes. Try it

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns sadly DoEvents doesnt change the amount of errors, i also tried  Application.Wait

Comment: Remove all the `On Error` and check if there is any previous error that later on can cause your problem

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks, thats a smart idea, i will try that